# Finding matrices with $A_1^{-1}+A_2^{-1}+\dots+A_k^{-1}=(A_1+A_2+\dots+A_k)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Prove that for any $n, k\geq2$ there exist nonsingular nondiagonal matrices $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_k \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$A_1^{-1} + A_2^{-1} + \dots + A_k^{-1} = \left( A_1 + A_2 + \dots + A_k \right)^{-1}$$

---

For $n=2$, if we have $A^{-1} + B^{-1} = (A+B)^{-1}$, if I am not mistaken, we can prove that $$\det(A)=\det(B)=\det(A+B)$$ if $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, so it would be natural to consider that $\det(A_1)=\det(A_2)=\dots=\det(A_k)$, but from here I don't have any idea what should I do. What should we do?

Comment: Should the main equation have $A_k$ instead of $A_n$?

Comment: @jobe Yep corrected

Comment: How about induction?

Comment: @BAI the difficult part is the base

Comment: What about skew diagonal matrices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $k$ is odd, then it is easy: take $A_{2m} = -A_{2m+1}$ for every $m\ge 1$ so that the whole expression reduces to $A_1^{-1} = A_1^{-1}$ that is true for every $A_1$ invertible.

If $k$ is even, then using the same trick as before, what's left is
$$
A_1^{-1} + A_2^{-1} = (A_1+A_2)^{-1}
$$
So if you solve it for $k=2$, you solve it for every $k$.

---

Let's prove that $n=3$ and $k=2$ produces an absurd. It turns out that
$$
2I + A_1A_2^{-1} + A_2A_1^{-1} = I
$$
and if $X = A_1A_2^{-1}$ then $X^{-1} = A_2A_1^{-1}$ and
$$
X^2 + X + I = 0.
$$
This means that the minimal polynomial of $X$ is $x^2+x+1$, so the characteristic polynomial must be $(x^2+x+1)^m$ for some $m$, but then $n=2m=3$, that is impossible.

Comment: Yeap, thanks man

Comment: @razvanelda Are you sure it is true? In the case $k=2,n=3$ it seems impossible to me

Comment: It could be wrong, this problem is from a book where I found a few mistakes, sorry if it is

Comment: @razvanelda I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

HINT

If the defining identity is left-right multiplied by $P^{-1}$ and $P$ then
$$
\eqalign{
  & P^{\, - 1} \left( {{I \over {A_{\,1} }} + {I \over {A_{\,2} }} +  \cdots  + {I \over {A_{\,k} }}} \right)P = \left( {{I \over {PA_{\,1} P^{\, - 1} }} +  \cdots  + {I \over {PA_{\,k} P^{\, - 1} }}} \right) =   \cr 
  & P^{\, - 1} {I \over {A_{\,1}  + A_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + A_{\,k} }}P = {I \over {PA_{\,1} P^{\, - 1}  +  \cdots  + PA_{\,k} P^{\, - 1} }} \cr} 
$$
thus $\{PA_kP^{-1}\}$ also satisfies the identity.

Comment: you got something wrong:  ${I \over {L^{\,1} }} + {I \over {L^{\,2} }} +  \cdots  + {I \over {L^{\,k} }} = {{I - L^{\, - k} } \over {L\left( {I - L^{-1}} \right)}}$

Comment: @Exodd: yep, you are right, thanks for signalling